# Why do I need to pass the type for one param and not for another if they're the same type?

Tags: unit-testing, go

Here's the playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/uiW2j6Zlj1d

In this specific part here:

```golang
    checkSums := func(t testing.TB, got, want []int) {
        t.Helper()

        if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, want) {
            t.Errorf("got %v want %v", got, want)
        }
    }
```

Why do I need to pass the type `[] int` to the `want` parameter, but passing this very same type to the `got` parameter is optional?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/basics/5

Comment: Because the language spec says so.

Answer (score 2):

This is given by the language specifications:.

In [Function Declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations) the specs define:

```
FunctionDecl = "func" FunctionName Signature [ FunctionBody ] .
```

The signature then includes the parameter declaration:

```
ParameterDecl  = [ IdentifierList ] [ "..." ] Type .
```

And finally the identifier list is under [Constant declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_declarations):

```
IdentifierList = identifier { "," identifier } .
```

Therefore, this equals to a comma-separated list of identifiers, optionally the vararg token `...` and finally the type:

```
ParameterDecl  = [ identifier { "," identifier } ] [ "..." ] Type .
```